# allocating and deleting a pointer of an observer base class in a derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, tensor

i'm learning how to manage pointers in c++, since i need to do some numerical work.

Is it okay to have an observer pointer in a base class, and then taking ownership in a derived class?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class TensorExpression {
    public:
    using scalar = float;
    using pointer = scalar *;

    virtual ~TensorExpression() = default;

    TensorExpression(pointer data, std::vector<std::size_t> shape)
    :   data_ptr(data)
    ,   shape_(shape)
    {}

    protected:
    pointer data_ptr;

    private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> shape_;
};

class Tensor : public TensorExpression {
    public:

    Tensor(std::vector<std::size_t> shape)
    :   TensorExpression(new scalar[memory_size(shape)], shape)
    {}

    ~Tensor() override {
        delete[] data_ptr;
    }

    private:

    std::size_t memory_size(std::vector<std::size_t> shape) {
        std::size_t size = 1;
        for(auto s : shape) size *= s;
        return size;
    }
};
```

Also, if I want to change to an a smart pointer aproach after i understand this, will it be harmful if i'm planning to do gpu programming?

Comment: Since you are dealing with a raw owning pointer (`float*`), you can do what you like to it anywhere. Just be sure who's the current owner so you don't delete it twice.

Comment: in my case, only Tensor is able to delete the pointer, all other derived class will just be observers as the base class. But since i'm planing to delete Tensor from it's base class pointer, I'm worried i will be producing issues in the future.

Comment: It's an unusual setup, but as long as you remember who's owning it (and do a proper implementation of [_"the rule of five_"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)) you could do it like this.

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds you should wrap those tensor allocated pointers into appropriate `std::unique_ptr` to make current ownership clear.

Comment: Yes, what @πάνταῥεῖ mentions is probably a better approach. Implement `unique_ptr` yourself and then use that home made wrapper.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Does that also work for inplace new?

Answer (score 1):

I would make the following changes to your code (code stripped down to the basics for clarity):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class TensorExpression {
    public:
    using scalar = float;
    using pointer = scalar *;

    virtual ~TensorExpression() {
        delete [] data_ptr;
    }

    TensorExpression(pointer data)
    :   data_ptr(data)
    {}

    protected:
    pointer data_ptr = nullptr;
};

class Tensor : public TensorExpression {
    public:

    Tensor()
    :   TensorExpression(new scalar[memory_size(shape)])
    {}
};
```

The point is, that if the base class *declares* `data_ptr`, it should also be responsible for destroying it (no matter who created it).  It also needs to initialise it (I always do that, regardless).

This puts you in a position to do the following, down the line, if you ever need to / want to:

- `data_ptr` can be made a smart pointer (recommended) - that would be a simple drop-in change
- you can add other classes that derive from `TensorExpression`

Also (for production code), read up on the [rule of 3 / 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), else you have written yourself a time bomb here.

And of course, `std::vector` is the method of choice for allocating storage like this as it manages that automatically.

Comment: I know about 3/5 rule, is just a prototipe, the problem with that is that i need to work with Eigen library or CUDA, and if a i put a destructor in the base class, and i decide to pass a pointer of a block of memory wrapped in a tensor expression, i will get double free violation.

Comment: @EricCardozo So, the API says that it takes over the overship of the raw owning pointer? If so, not a problem, remove `delete[] data_ptr;`

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes i need to initialize my data with some custom distribution. The issue I'm trying to solve is something like optional ownership. Sometimes creating a Tensor that owns a pointer and is responsible for deletion, but also passing lighweight views of that tensor and making operations with some extenal libraries. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I think I'm solving it refactoring my code with a third class, a TensorBuffer, with optional ownership. A destructor that deletes the data given a bool member is_owner. So a Tensor can be just a view or allocate a block of memory.

Comment: This all sounds awfully complicated (and error prone).  I think you should add an example of how you want to _use_ your class to your question.  We can probably suggest a way to make it all nice and simple.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo was right, I could just remove the destructor ad rely in another entity to manage the memory. I don't know why I was complicating my self to much.